# HTML 5 webworkers with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I just got into HTML5 webworkers and now I want to pass multiple arguments to my worker.

I have this in my page:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var server_url = 'localhost';
w.postMessage(username,server_url);
```

and this in my worker:

```
var username = '';
var server_url = '';

onmessage = function (e,f) {
    username = e.data;
    server_url = f.data;
}
console.log(username);
console.log(server_url);
```

and when I open it the page which calls the worker in the browser:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': The 2nd argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties.`

all I want to do is have the `username` and `server_url` getting passed to the worker
I know that in the examples I hardcoded the `server_url`, but in the real script, it's dynamic.

Please don't just say: change this, do that, but provide me with code so I can see how it should be done rather than still having to figure it out myself.

Comment: pass as many arguments in a single json like this w.postMessage({user:username,url:server_url});

Comment: hmm... I see.  
and then how do I read them in the worker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Post like this:

```
w.postMessage({ 
    user: username, 
    url: server_url 
})
```

on message event do:

```
onmessage = function (e) {
    username = e.data.user;
    server_url = e.data.url;
}
```

Comment: that did the trick :) 
altho I got an `undefined` username which was solved easily by changing `w.postMessage({user:username,url:server_url})` to `w.postMessage({username:username,url:server_url})`

Comment: Remove the parameter 'f' from the function. That is not needed and is creating a confusion.